# Ionic 4 Failed to Compile (angular 6)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
IONIC 4.2.1 and Angular 6 Errors.

 my project running good until recently i had added environment file,
    named dev environment.dev.ts since below error is haunting me.
```

Bellow error occurs on ionic serve --prod env=--prod command where as ionic serve works well.

ERROR in  Type HomePage in /Users/aniket/projects/ionic4-angular6-crud/src/app/home/home.page.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in /Users/aniket/projects/ionic4-angular6-crud/src/app/app.module.ts and HomePageModule in /Users/aniket/projects/ionic4-angular6-crud/src/app/home/home.module.ts! Please consider moving HomePage in /Users/aniket/projects/ionic4-angular6-crud/src/app/home/home.page.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in /Users/aniket/projects/ionic4-angular6-crud/src/app/app.module.ts and HomePageModule in /Users/aniket/projects/ionic4-angular6-crud/src/app/home/home.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HomePage in /Users/aniket/projects/ionic4-angular6-crud/src/app/home/home.page.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in /Users/aniket/projects/ionic4-angular6-crud/src/app/app.module.ts and HomePageModule in /Users/aniket/projects/ionic4-angular6-crud/src/app/home/home.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you have declared the HomePage in two modules such as **`AppModule`** and **`HomePageModule`**.

Remove it from the **`AppModule`**

Comment: it occurs only when i bootstrap the application with this  command.                       
        ionic serve --prod env=--prod

Comment: tries with ionic build --prod env=--prod also does not work

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-build-prod-error-type-in-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules/87350/9

Comment: so did that help?

Comment: i tried with combination you said but couldn't able to do it so for now working without environment files and above error won't appear in the case.